# How to show that Littlewood-Paley operator is almost projection?

Tags: fourier-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

The Littlewood-Paley operator is sometimes also improperly known as a projection since $$||P_kP_kf||_{L^p}\approx ||P_kf||_{L^p}$$

I wish to prove this fact so this would mean I'd need to show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that$$\frac{1}{C}||P_kP_kf||_{L^p} \stackrel{(1)}{\le} ||P_kf||_{L^p} \stackrel{(2)}{\le} C ||P_kP_kf||_{L^p}$$

I am able to show the first inequality since the annulus test function (let's call it $\chi_k$) is – by definition – less than $1$ in the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I am not able to establish the second inequality. I've tried invoking the definition of $\chi_k$ again but this time, I am unable to pin down the exact constant here since $\chi_{k\pm1}\chi_k$ not necessarily less than $(\chi_k)^2$. How should I go about proving this?

Comment: I don't think that's what the $\approx$ should mean, and are you sure you can get the pointwise inequality through the inverse fourier transform?

Comment: It is defined as $P_kP_kf \lesssim P_kf$ and $P_kf \lesssim P_kP_kf$, with $g \lesssim h$ meaning $\exists C>0$ such that $g \le Ch$. This is equivalent to the 2 inequalities I have above. 

As for whether the pointwise inequality through inverse Fourier exists, I am not sure. But ultimately, this estimate is invoked in many proofs so I'd think the conclusion is correct; I just don't know how to get to this conclusion.

Comment: Can you give an example of a proof where $\forall x :P_kP_kf(x) ≤ C P_k f(x)$ is used, and not some weaker inequality like $\|P_kP_k f\|_{L^p} ≤ C\|P_k f\|_{L^p}$? And the version I am familliar with has $P_k P_k f \approx  \tilde  P_k f$ with $\tilde P_k$ not quite the same as $P_k$

Comment: My apologies, I think you're right in that most of the proof I've saw uses $||P_kP_kf||_{L^p} \approx ||P_kf||_{L^p}$; I have edited the question to this case. How does one show that $||P_kf||_{L^p} \le C ||P_kP_kf||_{L^p}$?